# Double foreach loop

Tags: netlogo

I have the following code.

```
turtles-own [age]

set list1 (list 2 1 4 6)
set list2 (list (turtle 1) (turtle 0) (turtle 0) (turtle 0))

foreach list2 [ x ->
  foreach list1 [ y ->
     if (position x list2 = position y list1) [
       ask x [ set age (item(position y list1) list1 ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

What I am trying to do is to iterate though the list of turtles and the list of ages. If the index of the turtle matches the index of the value then set turtle's age to that value. I works to some extent but it appears that the values in list1 affects the foreach loops in some way. For example, I use sliders to determine the age values in list1. List1 one is written in the form `list1 (list a1 a2 a3 a4)` and for each a1, a2 a3, a4 I have a slider. Depending on the values I set on the slider, some turtles get the values while other don't.Sometimes all turtles get the age values, all depending on the values I set using the slides.

If there is a better way to do this then that would also be helpful. All I need is to use a loop that would set age values to their corresponding turtle. I have a much larger list of turtles which is why I need to use a loop.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`position` only reports the first value of the item in the list. In this example, for every `turtle 0` in your `foreach` loop, the `position x list2` will report 1. For this to work as-is, I think you'd need to have every item in each list be unique.

Not exactly sure what you're after here, but I think you can get around your issue by just including a counter in each loop, and use that to compare index values, as well as setting `age` using `item`:

```
turtles-own [age]
globals [ list1 list2 ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 2
  set list1 (list 2 1 4 6)
  set list2 (list (turtle 1) (turtle 0) (turtle 1) (turtle 0))

  let l2counter 0
  foreach list2 [ x ->
    let l1counter 0
    foreach list1 [ y ->
      if l2counter = l1counter [
        ask x [
          set age item l1counter list1
          show ( word "my age is now " age )
        ]
      ]
      set l1counter l1counter + 1
    ]
    set l2counter l2counter + 1
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

**Edit:**

If you don't *need* to use indexing, this is probably the better way:

```
to setup-2
  ca
  crt 2
  set list1 (list 2 1 4 6)
  set list2 (list (turtle 1) (turtle 0) (turtle 1) (turtle 0))

  ( foreach list2 list1 [
    [ _turt _age ] ->
    ask _turt [
      set age _age
    ]
    ]
  )  
end
```

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @OctavianBordeanu Glad it helped! Just a head up, I edited in a secondary approach that you may want to look at that I think accomplishes the same thing, but without having to use counters. It should be more efficient as it doesn't loop through `list1` for every value in `list2`.

Comment: This is much cleaner and easy to read. A good thing to learn for myself. Thanks!